# Could not launch './qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

With 25rc1 of the SDK tools I am having a problem when starting the emulators from $PATH

```
➜  ~  which emulator
/home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/tools/emulator
➜  ~  emulator @M 
Could not launch './qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
➜  ~  /home/ligi/bin/android-sdk/tools/emulator @M
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

Anyone knows a workaround? I could write a script to start emulators and cd in tools before but perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: you are facing the consequences of **`rc`** in the version number ...

Comment: ... and I will recommend [to fill the bug report,](http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs/emulator) write the script and forget about this (unless you would face the same bug in next "RC" release)

Comment: I think it is good style to sometimes consult stackoverflow before filing an issue

Comment: Duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902207/7428622)

Comment: I would rather say the other one is a duplicate of this one - look at the dates ;-)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I encounter this one in android studio 2.3 which use new path for the emulator so try the following:

do not use *emulator* executable in the: *sdk-path/tools/* directory but instead use the one found in the : *sdk-path/emulator/*

and also remove or rename the *emulator* found in the *sdk-path/tools* directory.

and because android sdk shipped with it's own *libstdc++.so.6* you need to do the following to avoid the libGL error:

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
```

Comment: Launching `sdk-path/emulator/emulator` helped me without overwriting libstdc++. So I just added `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` to $PATH before  `$ANDROID_HOME

Comment: I went for an alias. `alias emulator=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/emulator`.

Comment: @kim3er Thanks. Add alias into ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc worked for me.

Comment: In the sdk path I do not found any emulator and it is only available inside the sdk/tools folder. What changes we need to make it

Answer (score 25):

Try this, it work for me on Windows.

*Tools* **->** *Android* **->** *SDK Manager* **->** *SDK Tools* **->** *Android Emulator*

Then click on *Apply*.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If you're launching the emulator from command-line, try setting the current directory to your android sdk "tools" folder first.

This works for me as a workaround:

```
pushd ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
emulator -avd ${EMULATOR_NAME} -wipe-data&
popd
```

Answer (score 8):

This one works for me on MacOS Sierra.

Preference -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools (tab)

Tick on Android Emulator and Apply

Comment: This was the culprit for me

Comment: Wow! I had installed emulator and it was now found it Android Emulator is unchecked

Answer (score 5):

I had the `Android Emulator` up to date under `SDK Tools`. But I was still getting the error. Adding the following line to `~/.bash_profile` solved the problem for me:

```
PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 19.10!

With the environment variables already configured ($ANDROID_HOME), you should be able to list the AVDs, but if you are unable to start the AVD, do the following:

# Check the AVD target name

> emulator -list-avds

# But to start do:

> $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @avd_name

or

> /home/$USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @avd_name

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT is not set in your environment

Answer (score 0):

In Virtual device configuration, set Emulated performance to Software GLES 2.0

Answer (score 0):

yah my dns is blocked in the region i am visiting so i was searching for a way to add dns servers and start emulator at command line. default emulator in path did not work. instead go to your android SDK home and you'll see a emulator in there.  use that emulator executable like this:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26 -dns-server 8.8.8.8,208.67.222.222,199.85.126.10,8.8.4.4
```

i think you can give 4 dns's.  anyway this is a side note. back to the issue:

people here did not mention much that you need the -avd flag with it.  wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator`, it will cause error when you launch every time unless you change dir.

There is a another emulator in `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator`.It is a good choice