# Could not launch emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried to launch application in emulator in android Studio in ubuntu 14.04 and it shows the following errors.

1. Error shown while gradle build is in process:

> /home/next/NTE/MachineSetup/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -netdelay
>   none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_24 
>   Could not launch
>   '/home/next/NTE/MachineSetup/android-sdk-linux/tools/qemu/linux-x86/qemu-system-x86_64':
>   No such file or directory

2. Error appear after gradle build completed:

> 12/02 16:47:57: Launching app Error while waiting for device: The
>   emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_24 was killed.

I have attached screenshots for your reference.

[image: Error appears during gradle build]

[image: Error that appears after build finished]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The first error's reason is below:

There are two emulators: one in `$SDK/tools`, another one in `$SDK/emulator`.
The one in `$SDK/tools` cannot start.

Please place `$SDK/emulator` before `$SDK/tools` in your $PATH variable, it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, good spot. Exactly as you said, my `$SDK/tools` was before `$SDK/emulator`

Comment: try this, it work for me: install Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android Emulator

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Android Studio 2.3: edit file : **.profile**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
```

before

```
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
```

Like:[image]

Comment: this solution didn't work on Mac 10.11.6. I'm trying to launch emulator with command emulator @emulator_name

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help for you but I was seeing this error trying to run emulator in the console. I changes the ANDROID_SDK to point to the bin folder in my .bash_profile and that corrected the issue

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk

export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_HOME/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

I try with this code in `.bashrc` now it's working:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/AccountName/Android/Sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
```

Answer (score 1):

1: add `$SDK/emulator` in your `$PATH variable`
2: remove `$SDK/tools` in your `$PATH variable`
3: adb kill-server
4: adb start-server
5: Start the emulator from the command line

Example:
emulator @Pixel_XL_API_23

Answer (score 1):

It may be Android Emulator is not installed.

To add it to the Android Studio installation, go to `Tools->Android->SDK Manager`, select the `SDK Tools` tab, then ensure that `Android Emulator` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked around to find some similair posts that encountered what you did, for  the 1st error I found this that might fix the issue:

[qemu-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34266247/could-not-launch-qemu-windows-x86-64-qemu-system-i386-exe-no-such-file-or-d/34348073)

for the second one:

I saw multiple people that had this issue (source not super relevant). Some recommended updating your android studio or the SDK. Seeing as this might intervene with the 1st error I recommend just doing the 1st step and then check again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this happened for me when I had the system image installed — but not the emulator itself.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue today. These are steps i did and now working fine. I am using `arch-linux` os.

process will be same on `.bashrc` too.

```
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${PATH}
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${PATH}
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}
```

I faced error due to exporting path to `tools` directory instead of `bin` directory in tools.

`export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${PATH}`

This solution is for `android-sdk`.

Answer (score -1):

Try copy 'lib' folder from your Android sdk location /Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/qt/lib to ../Android/Sdk/tools/lib/qt/lib