# Android Studio Cannot launch AVD in emulator No such file or directory

Tags: android

I installed Android Studio 2.1.2 in Windows 8.1 64bit operating system, having 4gb ram and Core M processor (1 Ghz).

I have installed jdk and jre, furthermore i have  set path to ( C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin) and JAVA_HOME to (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121).

The very first issue i am having that i cannot open Android SDK manager by all mean. I tired to open this from sdk directory and from Andriod Studio as well but it does not get open. For this issue, i tired to many solutions but nothing worked for me (including android.bat setting).

The main issue that is annoying me that whenever i try to run my basic application in android studio i get the error:

(
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Could not launch 'C:\Users\Kaz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory
)[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0EtX.jpg)

I followed the path to check directory existence it is there. The thing i know that i may need to change the '/' after 'emulator' but i cannot find the way to try this solution.
I tried to run 'qemu-system-i386.exe' manually , but faced the notification "this app can't run on your PC".
Please give me any solution that could help me to overcome this problem, i have spent 2 days and tried every single solution on Internet and stackoverflow but could not solve this.

Comment: Duplicate of  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902207/7428622)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not launch emulator in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931254/could-not-launch-emulator-in-android-studio)