# -list-avds then launch results in PANIC

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I listed the emulators using:
`emulator -list-avds`

Attempt to launch an emulator:
`emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_25`

And terminal replies:
PANIC: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_XL_API_25], use -list-avds to see valid list.
ANDROID_AVD_HOME is defined but could not find Pixel_XL_API_25.ini file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME
(Note: avd is searched in the order of $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and $HOME/.android/avd)

[image: Has anyone encountered this?]

The path actually seems off:
`echo $ANDROID_AVD_HOME`
Produces: 
/Users/alex/.android

Which should be: /Users/alex/.android/avd

Fixed that, new exception:
[140737069994944]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that worked helped was to update my bash profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator
```

[Could not launch emulator in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931254/could-not-launch-emulator-in-android-studio)

*Note:*
I still can't use the GUI integrated into Android Studio. I have to run the emulator command:

```
sudo emulator -avd Nexus_Emulator
```