# Cannot launnch Avd emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23
[5064]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe': No such file or directory
```

This error message popsup whenever i try to run my Run Android Emulator.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not launch emulator in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931254/could-not-launch-emulator-in-android-studio)

Comment: Re-install system images of your android device.

Answer (score 0):

**Note you must have Internet Connection :**
Start Android studio...
On left top corner there is button sdk manager and select all possible options on SDK platforms and SDK tools...
Then click on apply or Ok...
Let it complete it will take some time around 1 2 hrs.

**Another solution**
If your friend has working android studio
copy it's sdk
SDK Location can be found by starting Android studio: File -> Other Setting - >
Default Project Structure ..
here you find the path copy..
go to that directory copy entire folder into your pendrive or HDD (it maybe 2 or 3 gb) then paste it into your computer..
remember that directory..
open your android studio.. 
File -> Other Setting - >
Default Project Structure
Here set that directory...